# jQuery only works on first page of DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable, datepicker

I have a DataTable [image]used to displaying info loading from a SQL table. In the last cell of each row I have a jQuery datepicker input. On the first page, the datepicker for each row works perfectly fine. As well as my jQuery function to check for a blank field before submitting. The problem is that on any other page I have the field checker AND more importantly, the datepicker does not work at all. I have looked on the https://datatables.net/faqs/index in order to see how to properly initialize my table but still no luck after trying the example given. Any suggestions would be appreicated.

Each of the datepicker's are assigned the class 'datepicker' when created. I use this class as the selector for the inputs in my jQuery scripts. Below is my code for the ASP.NET MVC View page I have:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data
@using System.Data
@using System.Data.SqlClient
@using System.Data.OleDb
@using System.Configuration
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using bp_open_issues.Models
@model bp_open_issues.Models.HomeView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BullPen Open Issues - Edit";
}
@{
    if (null != TempData["msg"])
    {
        if ("Added" == TempData["msg"])
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Record succesfully added.');
            </script>
        }
        else if ("Updated" == TempData["msg"])
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('Record closed.');
            </script>
        }
    }
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <section class=" featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h3 style="display: inline">Zone: </h3>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SZView.ZoneSet, Model.SZView.ZoneSet.ToList(), new { id = "zoneSelect" })
        <br /><h3 style="display: inline">Station: </h3>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SZView.LineSet, Model.SZView.LineSet.ToList(), new { id = "lineSelect" })
        <center><h1 style="display:inline">BULLPEN OPEN ISSUES</h1></center>
    </div>
</section>
}
<h3>Current Issues:</h3><br />
<div class="datagrid">
<table id="reviewTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ZONE<br />area</th>
            <th>STATION<br />resource</th>
            <th>WHEN<br />opened</th>
            <th>WHAT<br />is the concern</th>
            <th>WHY<br />do we have</th>
            <th>HOW<br />do we fix</th>
            <th>WHO<br />is responsible</th>
            <th>WHEN<br />is it fixed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Issue issue in Model.IssueSet.IssueList)
        {
            <tr class="altsec" id="@issue.RowID">
                <td>@issue.Zone.ToString()</td>
                <td>@issue.Station.ToString()</td>
                <td>@issue.WhenOpened.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@issue.What.ToString()</td>
                <td>@issue.Why.ToString()</td>
                <td>@issue.How.ToString()</td>
                <td>@issue.Who.ToString()</td>
                <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <fieldset><input type="text" style="width: 100px; display: none" value="@issue.ID" name="stringID" /><input class="datepicker" type='text' style="width: 100px" name="stringDate" id="@issue.DateID" /><input class="updateButtons" type="submit" style="float:right; padding: 2px 8px; margin: 1px;color: #ff0000;border: 1px solid #000;-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; background:#000;background-color:#000;" value="Update" /></fieldset>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reviewTable').DataTable();
    $('tr:even').css('background-color', '#EBEBEB');
    $('tr:odd').css('background-color', '#FFF');
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $('#selectFilter').change(function () {
        alert('zone was changed.');
        $(".all").hide();
        $("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
    });
    $('#zoneSelect').change(function () {
        $('#lineSelect').val('ALL');
        $(".altsec").hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var zoneVal = $this.find(":selected").attr("value");
        if (zoneVal != "ALL") {
            $('tr:has(td:contains("' + zoneVal + '"))').each(function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".altsec").show();
        }
    });
    $('#lineSelect').change(function () {
        $('#zoneSelect').val('ALL');
        $(".altsec").hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var lineVal = $this.find(":selected").attr("value");
        if (lineVal != "ALL") {
            $('tr:has(td:contains("' + lineVal + '"))').each(function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".altsec").show();
        }
    });
    $(".updateButtons").click(function (event) {
        var blankField = false;
        var dateVal = $(this).prev().val();
        if (dateVal == 0 || dateVal == null) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Please select a valid date.");
        }
    });
    (function () {
        var oldVal;

        $('#searchBar').on('change textInput input', function () {
            var val = this.value;
            if (val !== oldVal) {
                oldVal = val;
                if ($('#searchBar').text == "") {
                    $(".altsec").hide();
                    var zoneVal = $('#zoneSelect option:selected').text();
                    var lineVal = $('#lineSelect option:selected').text();
                    if (zoneVal == "ALL" && lineVal == "ALL") {
                        $(".altsec").show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Instead of using DataTable's page.dt event as when to call $('.datepicker').datepicker(), use the event **draw.dt** which will wait for the table rows to be loaded first and then execute the correct Javascript code.

Like such:

```
$('#reviewTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
        $('#reviewTable').ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $('tr:even').css('background-color', '#EBEBEB');
                $('tr:odd').css('background-color', '#FFF');
                $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: May I suggest reducing this code a bit for better readability and performance.

`
    $(function () {
        $('#reviewTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
            $('tr:even').css('background-color', '#EBEBEB');
            $('tr:odd').css('background-color', '#FFF');
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
    });
`

Answer (score 0):

So here's why this happens. You are applying `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` from the `$(document).ready` function. So it works first time. Now when you paginate, the data table, the dom you applied the datepicker on is gone! And you never "re-apply" the datepicker input on new dom that came in after pagination.

To fix this you will have to hook into pagination event, and when you page is loaded, you should re-execute `$('.datepicker').datepicker();`.

For example:

```
 $('#reviewTable').on( 'page.dt',   function () {  
   $('.datepicker').datepicker();
 });
```

Same is true on any other events you are applying to the datatable. For any event listeners you can fix this by using jquery `on` function on the parent of the inputs, and it should be automatically re-applied.

For example changing events to something like below should fix your listeners disconnection after pagination problem:

```
$("reviewTable").on("#lineSelect","change",function(){ });

$("reviewTable").on(".updateButtons","change",function(){ });
```

Read more about this approach [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hey @Shaunak,thanks for the reply. I tried used the 'page.dt' event handler for the DataTable but as it states in the documentation - this event is fired before the table has been redrawn. So when i try to use: '$('#reviewTable').on('page.dt', function () {
            alert('page changed');
            $('tr:even').css('background-color', '#EBEBEB');
            $('tr:odd').css('background-color', '#FFF');
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });' all of this code is done before the elements in the table can even be properly referenced.

Comment: ah okay. I just updated my answer with that approach :(.. so then from within that event try to wrap the  `datepicker` inside a dom ready like so `$(function(){ $('.datepicker').datepicker();  })` see if that helps.

Comment: like this?: 
        $('#reviewTable').on('page.dt', function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("changing....pages!!!");
                $(function () {
                    $('tr:even').css('background-color', '#EBEBEB');
                    $('tr:odd').css('background-color', '#FFF');
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
                })
            });
        });

Comment: yes, does it work? If not,  It would really help if you can create a sample jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem. It will be easier to debug.

Comment: Still not working. I created a JFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4xpwLx5r/1/ and everything works fine on there. Just doesn't work in my actual code :(       @Shaunak

Answer (score 0):

do $('body').delegate('btn', 'click', function () {

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your answer! Your answer could benefit from an explanation about how your solution works.